# Add a div under links

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a `div` under a link when it is clicked and then have that box go away after the next link is clicked and then have another div box under the next link.

Here is a fiddle I'm working on  : http://jsfiddle.net/d0okie0612/geJM3/

HTML :

```
<div id="blackbar">
    <a class="link" href="#">Click here</a>
    <a class="link2" href="#">Click here</a>
    <a class="link3" href="#">Click here</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript :

```
$('a.link').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('<div class="whitebar"><p>1</p></div>').appendTo('div#blackbar');
});

$('a.link2').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('<div class="whitebar2"><p>2</p></div>').appendTo('div#blackbar');
});

$('a.link3').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('<div class="whitebar3"><p>3</p></div>').appendTo('div#blackbar');
});
```

​​
CSS :

```
#blackbar  { background: black; width: 900px; height: 200px;}
.whitebar  { background: white; width: 40px; height: 30px; border: solid purple; z-index: 1000;}
.whitebar2 { background: white; width: 40px; height: 30px; border: solid purple; z-index: 1000; position: absolute; left: 90px;}
.whitebar3 { background: white; width: 40px; height: 30px; border: solid purple; z-index: 1000; position: absolute; left: 190px;}
a { color:white;}
```

I'm still learning jQuery, I'm sure this code could be improved.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="blackbar">
   <a class="link" href="#">Click here</a>
   <div class="whitebar"><p>1</p></div>    
   <a class="link2" href="#">Click here</a>
   <div class="whitebar2"><p>2</p></div>        
   <a class="link3" href="#">Click here</a>
   <div class="whitebar3"><p>3</p></div>        
</div>
```

```
$('#blackbar a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings('div').hide().end().next().show()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x2ByZ/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#blackbar a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.whitebar').remove()
    $('<div />', {'class': 'whitebar', html: '<p>'+($(this).index()+1)+'</p>'})
        .appendTo('div#blackbar').css('left', $(this).offset().left);
});
​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/geJM3/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**Js**

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var classname = $(this).data('classname'); 
    var index = $this.index() + 1;
    var html = '<div class="dot '+classname + '"><p>' + index + '</p></div>';
    $('#blackbar').find('.dot').remove().end().append(html);

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="blackbar">
<a class="link" href="#" data-classname="whitebar">Click here</a>
<a class="link2" href="#" data-classname="whitebar2">Click here</a>
<a class="link3" href="#" data-classname="whitebar3">Click here</a>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#blackbar{background: black; width: 900px; height: 200px;}

.dot
{
    background: white; 
    width: 40px; 
    height: 30px;
    border: solid purple;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.whitebar2
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 90px;
}

.whitebar3
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 190px;
}
a{color:white}
```

​

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/geJM3/7/)**